# set multiple selected value on select2 multiple in asp.net dropdownlist from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I need to add multiple author under a book. So i have used "Select2 Multiple" in asp dropdownlist. I was able to insert data but in edit mode i can't assign multiple selected value on dropdownlist.

[image]

My dropdownlist in aspx page is

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAuthor" runat="server" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Author (s)" CssClass="form-control select2"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In C# i have tried as following but it add only one value. My c# code is

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dtAuthor.Rows)
        {
           ddlAuthor.Items.FindByValue(row["AUTHOR_ID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
```

Any suggestion about how can i set multiple selected value in edit mode from c#?

Comment: I suggest you to use [Drop Down CheckBoxList control](https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/)

Comment: My dropdown list will have thousand of data, so checkbox is a problem. Select2 suggestion is helpful in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a DropDownList to achieve this, use a listBox like this :

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="ddlAuthor" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" data-placeholder="Select Author (s)" CssClass="form-control select2"></asp:ListBox>
```

And your code behind will work.

EDIT :

Here is a example of code behind for you :

```
        //I bind my ListBox with random data 
        List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Flo", "Auteur", "Patrick","Test" };
        //Databind
        ddlAuthor.DataSource = data;
        ddlAuthor.DataBind();

        //Here is my selected values, i wish that this values are selected
        List<string> selected = new List<string>() { "Flo", "Patrick" };

        //Foreach value in my selected list i select the proper value in my listbox
        foreach (string row in selected)
        {
            ddlAuthor.Items.FindByValue(row).Selected = true;
        }
```

Comment: How to set selected list in ListBox from c#?

Comment: As you did in your post, your code behind will work with a listBox

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot. As perfect as i wanted.

Comment: You cant hit the answer button on my answer to "close" this question :)

Comment: I want to but can't because of reputation :(

Comment: Even if your reputation is low you can always mark an answer as the  answer in your own question , no ?

Answer (score 0):

you aren't using select2 in this case ! 
you need to use select2, and push all you multiple data into a variable and send it to js function or use ajax

```
$(".ddlAuthor").select2('data', youDataHere);
```