# Multiple dropdown is not working with Select2

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am not sure what's wrong with my dropdown button, it does not simply capture  the selected items in code behind.

This is my c# method

```
 public string GetComputerStudies()
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListItem item in ddComputerStudies.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                items.Add(item.Text);
            }
        }
        return String.Join(", ", items.ToArray());
    }
```

and this is my asp.net

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddComputerStudies" CssClass="form-control select2 js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"></asp:DropDownList>
```

When the foreach iterates it just takes the first value, and it ignores the other selected items.

Can somebody help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set multiple selected value on select2 multiple in asp.net dropdownlist from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069081/set-multiple-selected-value-on-select2-multiple-in-asp-net-dropdownlist-from-c-s)

Comment: That answer didn't work for me

Comment: It's actually different because in that post the values are already selected, my problem is that the dropdown only selects one value, the first one.

Comment: `DropDownList` will not allow you to select multiple values, you need to change the control

Comment: What control should use?

Comment: I need to display several options from the Database.